# Debug problems on Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()

Tags: magento-1.9, php, checkout, shopping-cart, debugging

I'm investigate a compatibility problem with two m1 extensions.

For this I need a simply output of any information I can get about `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()`.

I have tried following (single, not all together):

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/debug.txt', var_export($cart, 1), FILE_APPEND);   
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/debug.txt', print_r($cart, 1), FILE_APPEND);  
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/debug.txt', print_r(get_object_vars($cart), 1), FILE_APPEND);
```

But this leads to a crash while the execution (From the checkout submit (after clicking order), I fall back to the cart page). This is strange, because I use Information out of $cart, at the same place. Examp: `$checkoutCartQuote->getAllItems();` gives me the articles. Just 1 line above the `file_put_contents`. So why does it just crash when I try var_export/print_r it?

But more important: How do I now get an Output like `var_dump` or `print_r` on this object? I need to see any properties with any values.

As I work on a shop of a client, I only have limited FTP access and no access to apache log. The exception Log of M1 didn't got new lines since I started working today.

Comment: The Crash may isn't caused by file_put_contents, because I removed the line and it still crashes. But If I do an file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/debug.txt', 'foo 123' FILE_APPEND); at the same line, foo 123 appears in the debug.txt. While the other command from my question, doesn't generate something in debug.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely you're actually hitting a memory limit in PHP when trying to parse the entire quote object.
You could:

- Use a debugger, like xdebug, and inspect the data through that.
- append `->getData()`  to the end of `getQuote()` to get only the data fields, not the entire object.
- Increase the PHP memory limit, by using `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` at the top of the script (this should be fine for debugging, but don't commit this to production)

Personally, I'd go for the first one if you have the time.

Comment: Ty, the ->getData() worked for me. xdebug would be better, but I don't have this kind of access to the host.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData();`

I think the full quote object is too big to print.

Comment: Ty, this answer worked for me.